# CSS transition not working with max-height: fit-content

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate some expansible panel with a CSS like this:

```
.panel {
  transition: max-height 0.1s ease-in-out;
  flex: 90;
  max-height: 26px;

  &.expanded {
    max-height: fit-content;
  }
}
```

Problem is this transition is not working.  If I use some numeric `max-height` value in `.expanded`, it works perfect.

Any idea?

I read that `fit-content`, `max-content`, ... are not animatable.  Is that the case?

Comment: please add you HTML code. thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to specify a width

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: I think the best you could do is set your height to 26px and fit content and then animate your max-height from 26 to a height taller than your content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes fit-content and max-content are not animate your content. you have to provide some numeric value to the max-height for animate. it consider the height required to your content so you have to provide the value of max-height greater then your content height.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Problem is that I'd like to keep the behaviour of fit-content, so using a numeric value is not really an option.  I'll open a new question with what I'm trying to achieve to keep this answer clear (didn't find one earlier): max-height with non-numeric values like fit-content/max-content could not be animated.

Comment: @agascon Can you link your other question? One approach that comes to mind is 1) starting with invisible element (NOT gone) 2) using `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the content size 3) making the element `height:0;` by applying some class 4) using the returned height to generate `.expanded` CSS on the fly OR using a CSS variable to set the height.
I'll probably carelessly set it to `fit-content` and expect browsers to figure out animations in future as they can do it much quicker.

Answer (score -2):

Use viewport concepts!

```
&.expanded {
  max-height: fit-content;
}
```