# How to make transition in opening menu in sidebar with react + tailwind

Tags: reactjs

I tried to make transition to my sidebar menu (transition on opening) in React, the transition doesn't work and I don't understand why.
[I saw this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833316/add-transition-to-accordion-with-react-tailwind)

here is the code I used, everything work but the transition doesn't work. I want the menu to open slowly like an accordion.
Thank you in advance.

```
return (
  <>
    {SidebarData.map((menu) => {
      return (
        // Menu
        <div className="menu-item" key={menu.id}>
          ...
          
          {/* Menu Title */}
          <div className="menu-title">
            ...
            <Link to={menu.path}
              className="..."
              onClick={() => {
                handleSubNavExpand(menu);
                handleClick(menu.path);
              }}
            >
              ...
            </Link>
          </div>
          
          {/* Sub Menu Content */}
          {expanded && (
            <div className={`sub-menu overflow-hidden transition-[max-h-full] duration-700 ease-in ${expanded ? "max-h-40" : "max-h-0"}`}>
              {menu.subNav && menu.subNav.length > 0 && isActiveTab && (
                <ul className="relative m-0 list-none p-0">
                  {menu.subNav.map((subMenu) => {
                    return (
                      <li className="relative group" key={subMenu.id}>
                        <Link to={subMenu.path}
                          className="capitalize ..."
                          onClick={() => {
                            setActiveSubNav({ ...activeSubNav, selectedId: subMenu.path });
                            handleClick(subMenu.path);
                          }}
                        >
                          ...
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

Comment: The transition doesn't work because the class name was misspelled. I fixed the error and now the transition works. I consider the ticket closed.